# jquery selector for all elements except attributes in an array

Tags: jquery

I have a page with an array:

```
var idlist = ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3'];
```

This array references `<div>`s in my HTML with those IDs.  Each of these `<div>`s also has a class `.tabPage`.

I'm trying to write a selector that targets all `div.tabPage` elements, except for the ones with an ID in my array.  I found the `.not()` function in jQuery documentation, but how can I do this for multiple values?

Comment: use the multiple selector selector, it seems to be pretty common today. `"#id,#id2,#id3"`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: So, like: $('div.tabPage:not("#ID1"),div.tabPage:not("#ID2"),etc.) ?

Comment: @Paul: No, that would select all `div.tabPage` elements (because `div.tabPage:not("#ID2")` also selects the one with ID `ID1`, etc).

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('div.tabPage').not('#' + idlist.join(', #'));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hvXNq/).

If you prefer a more verbose approach, you could instead use filter (which will either remove, or retain, the elements from the selection):

```
$('div.tabPage').filter(function(){
    return idlist.indexOf(this.id) === -1;
}).addClass('jQueryFound');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hvXNq/1/).

References:

- [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- [`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Answer (score 0):

I think it might clearer if not done in the selector, but on the body of the executing code:

```
var ignoreList = ['foo', 'bar'];
$('.tabPage').each(function(){
    if(ignoreList.indexOf(this.id) > -1) return;

    // code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('div:not(#' + ids.join(',#')+')').end().click(function() { alert('hi'); });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jfmrn/

Comment: I'm not sure why [`end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) is there (since you've used only one selector (and no subsequent filtering, as I understand it)), but, more importantly, your demo doesn't seem to work: *every* `div` element generates an `alert()` when clicked. Which seems to go against the requirements of the question.